# JavaFx ListView for load Messages in chat application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i wanna write a chat app with a listview for messages item. 
it's load messages at top and bottom of listview. 
i want when messages added at top and bottom of listview scrollbar doesn't move.

(maybe this is because of javafx doesn't support  'cells of different lengths').

Answer (score 0):

Try check [ScrollTo Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo%28int%29) tabWiew also [ScrollTo Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) ListView you just tell witch index should be showed always

Comment: @Patric this not work correctly in listview with different height items

Comment: ListView if i know it take cares about line breaks and etc staffs so it doesnt metter if your msg Object is 25555 characters or 2 characters 

have you tryed Scroll to OBJECT, its better then INDEX in your case

Comment: @Patric bro. messages aren't just text. items are text, photo , photo with caption text and ,...

Comment: then last think is making Thered 

class Scroll extend Thread 

and just make some methods like scroll to end

some helpful tips : https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/javafx-tip-15-listview-autoscrolling.html